# Scheme Lisp The determinant of a 3 × 3 matrix

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

My code isn't working and it gives me an error saying: det: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 4
  given: 9
  arguments...:

This is my code:

```
(define (det3x3 a b c
                d e f
                g h i)
  (+ (* a ( * e i (* h f)))(* b (* d i (* g f)))(* c (* d h (* e g)))))
(display "(det 0 5 -6 8 -11 4 5 1 1) = ")(det 0 5 -6
                                              8 -11 4
                                              5 1 1)
```

Comment: I propose looking at the function `det`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

determinant = a(ei − fh) − b(di − fg) + c(dh − eg)

```
(define (det3x3 a b c
                d e f
                g h i)
  (+ (- (* a (- (* e i) (* f h)))
        (* b (- (* d i) (* f g))))
        (* c (- (* d h) (* e g)))))
```

e,g:

```
> (det3x3 0 5 -6
          8 -11 4
          5 1 1)
-318
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function `det` in the line with the call to `display`. Change this to `det3x3`. `det` must be defined as a 4-arity function. I'm not sure what version of Scheme you're using; that must be something else.

Comment: Im using DrRacket